# System.out.println - Syntax error

Tags: java

Beginner in Java here.

Trying to figure out why I am getting a syntax error on the last two System.out.println.

I tried moving my brackets around, but I end up with a never-ending loop.

I appreciate all of your help in advance!

---

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class GuessingGame 
{

    public static void main(String args []) 
    {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner (System.in);

        int random = (int) (Math.random()*20 +1);
        int numberOfAttempts = 0;
        boolean win = false;

        while (win == false)

            System.out.println("Guess the number (1 - 20)");
            int guess = scan.nextInt();
            numberOfAttempts++;

            if (guess == random)
                win = true;
            else if (guess < random)
                System.out.println("Your guess was low. Guess again.");
            else
                System.out.println("Your guess was high. Guess again.");
    }

            System.out.println("You guessed right! It took you guesses.");  
            System.out.println("Do you want to play again? (yes or no)");

}
```

Comment: You should indent your code properly. What is considered the body of a `while` loop? Voting to close for typographical error.

Comment: Thank you.  I'm still trying to figure out the indentation issues. The body of the while loops should be the "Guess the number" in which the guessing game executes.

Comment: 1. Use braces for every for/if/while/method/switch/class/etc. 2. Count your braces, every opening brace should have a closing brace

Comment: @Absurd-Mind - thank you. I had forgotten I needed to place the brackets. I'm marking as solved, but I am in Stackoverflow timeout since I opened this personal account. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your not opening the while loop. You need brackets after the while

```
while (win == false){
//need one at the beginning 

        System.out.println("Guess the number (1 - 20)");
        int guess = scan.nextInt();
        numberOfAttempts++;

        if (guess == random)
            win = true;
        else if (guess < random)
            System.out.println("Your guess was low. Guess again.");
        else
            System.out.println("Your guess was high. Guess again.");
} //and at the end
```

Comment: Fantastic! Thank you much. Only in week 3 of this Java course! Marking as solved.